# Code does not work without disabling SSL

Tags: php, curl, ssl

Please take a look at this code:

```
<?php
$url = "the_source_url";  
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
?>
```

This page is accessed by my Android app to get a date from some source. The `url` returns a json data, which I print back, then, in my app, I process the data and display it. This is working fine for me right now (I'm still in the testing phase).

I read in SO that disabling the `SSL` (whih I did in line 6) is *risky and not recommended*. However, I couldn't make my script work unless I disable it.

How to make it work without disabling the SSL? Or how to eliminate the risk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the certificate would make you vulnerable to man in the middle attack, You can download use the certificate

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE/cert.pem");
```

To get the certificate follow this guide

Then click on “View Certificate”:

[image]

Bring up the “Details” tab of the cerficates page, and select the certificate at the top of the hierarchy. This is the CA certificate.

[image]

Then click “Export”, and save the CA certificate to your selected location, making sure to select the X.509 Certificate (PEM) as the save type/format.

[image]

[Image Source : http://unitstep.net/](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/)

Comment: I'm using Google Places API. I couldn't find a certificate for it!

Comment: [Download the certificate](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/) then use it ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the option [`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) and set it to `false`:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

This disables SSL host verification so that you can access a host which uses a self-signed certificate. If the host has a valid certificate then check @Baba's answer

Security considerations:

The connection is encrypted and can't being sniffed that easy. But you can not make sure that the the server is the server. So a hacker could sniff traffic using a man in the middle attack. If you want to get sure you'll have to go @Babas way and import the certificate from the server

Comment: This would do what exactly?

Comment: Disables SSL host verification so that you can access a host which hasn't a signed certificate. Refer to the manual, I've linked it

Comment: Isn't that what `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` does? Which I believe is not safe in terms of security?