# PHP curl json for twitter not working

Tags: php, json, curl, twitter

This code is not working:

```
$ch = curl_init ("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/ijustine.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4");

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec ($ch);

var_dump($output);
```

If I try to access:
`https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/ijustine.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4`

From a browser by typing this address manually it works and json is displayed in browser.

But in my script it's not working.

I am using WAMP and curl extension in PHP (5.3.13) is activated because if I run: `var_dump( curl_version() );` I get the array where version is 7.25.0.

Btw. this is working:
    $ch = curl_init ("http://yahoo.com");

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec ($ch);

var_dump($output);
```

But if I try access `http://twitter.com` I get `string '' (length=0)`. And if I try `https://twitter.com` I get `boolean false` Why?

Do I need to enable any additional php extensions or some apache modules on my localhost or something else?

Comment: use `http` instead of `https`, otherwise add some `CURLOPT_SSL_*` options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't connect to HTTPS site using cURL. Returns 0 length content instead. What can I do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316099/cant-connect-to-https-site-using-curl-returns-0-length-content-instead-what-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code does not work without disabling SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374126/code-does-not-work-without-disabling-ssl) -- You should use the certificate with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a HTTPS certificate issue; check this past question:
[Can't connect to HTTPS site using cURL. Returns 0 length content instead. What can I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316099/cant-connect-to-https-site-using-curl-returns-0-length-content-instead-what-c)

Answer (score 0):

It's **very important** to note that, **very soon**, your code will no longer work because you are using the twitter api version 1.0, which is deprecated.

[This post explains what's going on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725588/twitter-api-url-search-for-username/16749689#16749689) in a short version.

Once you've read that, you can head over to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662) which explains exactly how to get the tokens you require for the 1.1 api.

Again, your code will **very shortly cease to work** with Twitter's 1.0 api. Your issue will no longer be that of connecting over HTTPS via cURL - you will get a "not authenticated" error on every request.

So use the above information to start using authenticated requests.