# How to open links of a tweet in a new tab / new window?

Tags: javascript, twitter, target, tweets

Dear stackoverflowers,

I am displaying the latest tweet on my website. However, when I have a tweet that contains a link, it opens the link the same window.

My best guess would be to add the target-value to the . 
But how can I do that? Is there a trick for the Twitter API. (Twitter API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

**How can I change, that it opens containing links of a tweet in a new window?**

.

Here is the markup that displays the latest tweet:

```
<div id="twitter_update_list"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=USERNAME&include_rts=true&count=1&callback=twitterCallback2"></script>
```

Comment: Solution found with javaScript.

Just by adding the target-value atrribute. 

    $('#twitter_update_list a').attr('target', '_new');

Comment: Dennis, if my answer helped at all, could you 'tick' it as correct, else I'll delete... cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a direct answer to your solution with your own findings: `$('#twitter_update_list a').attr('target', '_new');` simply so this has an answer there. Now for the more important stuff:

You have a **significant issue** with your code: You're using the version 1 API which is deprecated and will soon be *removed completely*. This means your code will just stop working. That's it.

Here is a recent post explaining what's going on, briefly: [Twitter API: Url search for Username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725588/twitter-api-url-search-for-username/16749689#16749689)

The difference is, your question is client-side and I do my stuff server-side with PHP. You will need to perform authenticated requests in the future. There are many resources out there to help you do this.