# Error in cURL Function

Tags: php, curl, https

hey i'm trying to cURL "**https://www.libertyreserve.com/captcha.jpg**"
so i tried to curl it but the result was "1x1" Gif Pic
then i reialized that the site want a cookie from the Login Page to show a valid Captcha 
i used function

```
$file['cookie'] = "cookie.txt";
function cURL_Page($url='',$var=''){
    global $file;
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,20);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.libertyreserve.com/en/login");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    if($var) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $var);
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE,$file['cookie']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$file['cookie']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$file['cookie']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}
```

then i cURL Login page

```
$LoginPage = cURL_Page("https://www.libertyreserve.com/en/login");
```

then cURl the PIC and put header and print it

```
$ImageCode = cURL_Page("https://www.libertyreserve.com/captcha.jpg");
header("Content-Type: image/gif");
echo $ImageCode;
```

but result still "1x1" bcz the curl function don;t save the cookies
p.s : the site response with  "Content-Type: image/gif" for that i put it in header

Answer (score 1):

**Few Observation**

- You are not properly sharing the `cookie` be cause you don't need `CURLOPT_COOKIE`
- Even if SSL verification is false .. you need to add certification information see [Code does not work without disabling SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374126/code-does-not-work-without-disabling-ssl/16374178#16374178) on how that can be done

**Here is a working code**:

```
$ch = new SharedCurl(__DIR__ . "\libertyreserve.crt");

try {
    $ch->get('https://www.libertyreserve.com/en/login');
    $image = $ch->get('https://www.libertyreserve.com/captcha.jpg');
    header("Content-Type: image/gif");
    echo $image;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Class Used**

```
class SharedCurl {
    private $ch;
    private $info;

    function __construct($cert) {
        $this->cookie = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
        $this->cert = $cert;
        if (! is_file($this->cert)) {
            throw new Exception("Can't find Certificate");
        }
    }

    function get($url) {
        $this->ch = curl_init($url);
        $this->shared();
        $responce = curl_exec($this->ch);
        $this->info = curl_getinfo($this->ch);

        if (curl_errno($this->ch)) {
            throw new Exception(curl_error($this->ch));
        }
        curl_close($this->ch);
        return $responce;
    }

    function shared() {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31');
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.libertyreserve.com/en/login");
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $this->cert);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    }
}
```

[Certificate File Used](https://mega.co.nz/#!bYBWkArQ!b8vN3g2EbFydxJpC_1IOImW4DA5_cCqF-oeRRPMar1M)