# Login through cURL to https website

Tags: php, curl

```
   $fields['username'] = "Pass@1234";
    $fields['password'] = "harsha";
    // set postfields using what we extracted from the form
    $POSTFIELDS = http_build_query($fields); 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://website.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/abc.crt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://website.com");
    $page = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
    echo $page;
```

i have save .pem file path in php ini
 but still it shows "SSL certificate problem unable to get local issuer certificate error"

Comment: have you debugged it? Especially the location of the .crt file...

Comment: yes the location of crt file is valid

Comment: actually i have login to facebook  with the above code successfully. but the site which i want to login shows the above error . and if i comment the line curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/abc.crt"); it redirects to the url but not get logged in

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688780/login-to-https-site-using-curl
go through this link
hope so it help you....